# Orthogonality of eigenvectors of $A$ and $A^T$ associated with different eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

I am trying to prove the following question:

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix.
1. In this part, entries, eigenvalues, and eigenvectors of $A$ may be imaginary (non-real complex) numbers. Show that if *v* is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with the eigenvalue α and *w* is an eigenvalue of $A^T$ with the eigenvalue β ≠ α, than prove *w<sup>T</sup>v* =0.

(Hint: *(A<sup>T</sup>w)<sup>T</sup> = w<sup>T</sup>(Av)*)

I was wondering if $A$ should be a symmetric matrix to prove. How should I approach it?

Comment: Wouldn't $A$ being symmetric defeat the whole point of specifying $A^T$ in lieu of $A$ in the first place?

Comment: You are right. My bad. Do you have any idea to show it?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your title which was quite... non-informative.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have to assume that $A^T=A$.

Indeed, identity: $$(A^Tw)^T\color{red}{v} = w^T(Av)\tag{1}$$

gives $$(\beta w)^Tv = w^T( \alpha v) \ \iff \ (\beta-\alpha)w^Tv=0$$

which is possible iff $w^Tv=0.$

**Remarks :**

1) I have added $\color{red}{v}$ in (1).

2) A similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2652526)

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!